# Is there a way to change referenced library files during processing?

Tags: vb.net, dll, workflow

I have a .NET customer framework that functions much like a Workflow. It uses reflection to get a listing of all of the processes it is capable of from a specific folder, and starts them via reflection with a known start point (all of them have a method called "Process"). Since these files are only called to do the processing and not part of the compile... is there a way for me to be able to drop in a new reference library (DLL) for one of the processes that is being updated without restarting the whole process?

Here is my flow...

START

- Load list of references
- Load work, assign to references
- After X Time, refresh references (or
  on WCF refresh command being sent)

Is it possible to do this, or do I do I need to actually stop and restart the assembly base to be able to recognized the new reference file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can with Assembly.Load but I think you need to look at [MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) first.

Comment: Unfortunately we are still on 3.5 framework, but that link is interesting for sure. I will give the Load a shot and see if it works. Thanks!